# How to save files with DownloadManager in private path?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have downloaded some files with `DownloadManager`, I want to save them where that no one can access them, I mean they are private, just my application can access them and I want after uninstall my app they get deleted. but according to my search `DownloadManager` can save files just in SDCard that everyone can see my files.
can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, File.separator + folderName + File.separator + fileName);
```

Where request is your DownloadManager.Request
This folder (sdcard/Android/data/your.app.package) is accessible to the user, but not visible in galleries (not scanned by media scanner), it's only accessible using file manager. Also, this folder will be deleted when your app gets deleted.

Comment: yes, I know but I do not want this folder be accessible by file manager

Comment: since download manager runs in a different process than your app it doesn't have permission to write to your app's internal storage.
You should implement your own download manager or use a library like this one:
https://github.com/majidgolshadi/Android-Download-Manager-Pro

Answer (score 0):

For Set Your Path For Download File Use: Work For me (Android 11).

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/YOUR FOLDER/", "YOUR FILE.(mp3|mp4|pdf|...)");

    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Complete Code:

First Check Directory

```
  private boolean CreateDirectory() {
boolean ret = false;
File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(filepath.getPath() + "/YOUR FOLDER/");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    try {
        dir.mkdirs();
        ret = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return ret;
}
```

Then:

```
     String URL = " YOUR URL ";

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(URL));
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setTitle("YOUR TITLE");
        request.setDescription("YOUR DESCRIPTION");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
   request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/YOUR FOLDER/", "YOUR FILE.(mp3|mp4|pdf|...)");

        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
        DownloadManager manager=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Long downloadId= manager.enqueue(request);
```

ok,Finish

Answer (score -1):

You can use internal storage path to save data internally and it will get deleted when your app will get uninstalled

```
String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: it goes to sdcard and everyone can see this

Comment: @Maryam getFileDir() returns the app's private internal storage. However, this answer doesn't specify how (or even if) that path can be passed to the DownloadManager.