# How to download a file to a specific folder

Tags: java, android, download-manager

I need to download a file to the getFilesDir directory of android so it is only accessible by the application. I am currently using Download Manager and I can only specify the Environment type. Please can I use a custom directory or is there another approach.

This is my download code:

```
public void download(){
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI| DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setTitle("Download");
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, File.separator + "lessons/1234.mp4");
    manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
    registerReceiver(downloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

Comment: Use an HTTP client API and download it yourself. I use [OkHttp for downloading files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).

Comment: Check comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744505/how-to-save-files-with-downloadmanager-in-private-path#comment66786872_39744924

Answer (score 0):

Define `relativePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "MyExternalStorageAppPath"`

And then use `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, relativePath, filename);`

Also don't forget to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your manifest.

So by using "setDestinationInExternalFilesDir" files will be download to the external memory dedicated to your app, so: "external_storage/Android/data/name_of_your_app/path_passed